# How to start code when pressed four Buttons in Android

Tags: java, android

I want to make pin input with Buttons and TextView in Android.
I have Textview for pin , and 9 Buttons for user to press as digits. 
What i want when user press four buttons to change my Textview letter by letter(Button by Button) , and when entered fourth button to start code

Here is image: [image: Layout]

Any tips please?

Here is my code:

content_main.xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/white"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.group.digit.razvoj.appointment.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/pinLayoutMain"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/left_margin_pin">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/pinTvLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/between_margin"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/between_margin"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pinTv"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="@string/pin"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/passLayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/pinEntry"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="****"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/firstRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b1"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b2"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="2"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b3"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="3"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/secondRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b4"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="4"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b5"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="5"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b6"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="6"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sthirdRow"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b7"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="7"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b8"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="8"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b9"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="9"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/forthow"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="1"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/b0"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="0"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/bback"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="-"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java:

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //init buttons
    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_PIN_NUM; i++) {
        buttonsPinWidget[i] = (Button) findViewById(buttonsPinId[i]);
    }

    pinentry = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pinEntry);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should to use one onClickListener for everyone button with switch case inside of it. 
In every case of switch case block your should addor delete (if you have the button for deleting) one character it TextView.
After switch case block check the text length in your TextView. If the length of it equals 4, you can try to authorization or login or other actions.

Sorry for bad English.

Comment: How to know what Button is for what letter. If i click on "1" Button how to know for what position it is in TextView?

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting question first of all. 
The only solution I can think of is to create a public method which will always check the length of the textview (which I think should be edittext) and add that method for every button. Once the length of the textview is 4, trigger your code you want. 
Let me know if you need some more clarification

Answer (score 0):

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String s=txtView.getText().toString();
            if(s.length()<3){
                s=s+btn.getText().toString();
                txtView.setText(""+s);
            }else if(s.length()==3){
                s=s+btn.getText().toString();
                txtView.setText(""+s);
                 // write your code 
            }
        }
    });
```